# Checkbox for every task echoed from a database

Tags: php, javascript, html, checkbox

I am trying to add a checkbox for every task that I echo from a database and call the function `changecompleted` whenever any checkboxe is selected.

```
echo $row_1['Task'];?>
<input type='checkbox' onclick="changecompleted(<?php $row_1['index']?>)">
```

Now when I try to use the change completed function like this

```
function changecompleted(idnumber) {
    document.getElementById('label5').innerHTML = idnumber;
}
```

label5 is changing to undefined or empty. Can someone tell me what the problem is?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What HTML is generated by the php? And an `input` element is a void element, which can't contain any other elements, so `innerHTML` isn't a valid property of such an element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 echo $row_1['Task'];?>
 <input type='checkbox' onclick="changecompleted(<?php echo $row_1['index']?>)">
```

You're getting undefined because you aren't echoing the index value, therefore it's calling the js function with 0 args and idnumber is really undefined.